# Getting a 403 error with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

The `gitWebRequest.GetResponse()` line is returning a `403 error` from the server and I can't seem to figure out why.  Any help appreciated.

```
            var address = new Uri(verifyUrl + _apiKey);

            HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            var gitWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            gitWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            gitWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            var requestReader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);

            var requestBody = requestReader.ReadToEnd();

            var myRequestUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",request.Url.Scheme,request.Url.Authority.TrimEnd('/'), request.RawUrl);

            var verifyRequestData = new { requestUri = myRequestUri, postBody = requestBody };

            var gitRequestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(verifyRequestData));

            using (var stream = gitWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(gitRequestData, 0, gitRequestData.Length);
            }

            using (var response = gitWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                if (response != null)
                {
                    var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can we see the url requested? Additionally are you posting anything or  could you change to gitWebRequest.Method = "GET";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was using http instead of https, which is what goole requires.

Thanks for making me look at the url.